# Bases for image and kernel of a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T$ be the linear map $\mathbb R^4 \rightarrow \mathbb R^3$ given by
$(w, x, y, z)$$\rightarrow$ $(x + 2y + z, z − w, 2x + 4y + 2w)$.
Give bases for its image and kernel.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

For a basis of the kernel, use row reduction; you'll obtain a set of linearly independent equations for the kernel. You should find the kernel has dimension $2$.

For a basis of the image, use row reduction on the transpose of the matrix. The non-zero lines are those of a basis of the image.